# regex for a word but avoiding it if they are making another word

Tags: php, regex

Data:

`Japan is beautiful country.
AU is the telecom company of japan, au networks are very good.
Japan is famous for good restaurants.`

---

I need a RegEx to find the `'au'` or `'AU'` only even if have spaces before and after, but if it is within a word like `'beautiful'` and `'restaurants'` I want to avoid it.

#### Attempts

```
"/(?:au)/"

"/\P{au}/u"

"/(?:\A|\s)au(?:\s|\Z)/"

"/[^a-zA-Z]/"
```

---

```
if($word == 'au') {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is assert word boundaries on either sides of the string in a case-insensitive manner:

`\bau\b /ig`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/od4u90/1)

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and just remove global handler if you want to search one time.

```
/(( )|^)(au)(( )|$)/gmi
```

I'm not sure what language you're using.  I would match it using Perl with below method.

```
my $string = "Japan is beautiful country. AU is the telecom company of japan, au networks are very good. Japan is famous for good restaurants.";
my $matched; 
if($string=~m/(( )|^)(au)(( )|$)/gmi) {
   $matched = $2; ## This is AU, au Au or aU
}
## do something with $matched here
```

Sample of the match below.

[image]

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you might just want a word boundary with an `i` flag.

#### Test

```
$re = '/\bau\b/si';
$str = 'Japan is beautiful country. AU is the telecom company of japan, au networks are very good. Japan is famous for good restaurants.AU not-au';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "AU"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "au"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "AU"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "au"
  }
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KoI4WZ/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/KoI4WZ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: Why is `/s` required?

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

You can use use

```
(?<=\s|^|\.|,)au(?=\s|$|\.|,)
```

- `(?<=\s|^|\.|,)` - Asserts match should be preceded by `space, start of string, . or ,`
- `au` - Matches `au`
- `(?=\s|$|\.|,)` - Asserts match should be followed by `space, end of string, . or ,`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/exmMN5/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert what is directly on the left and directly on the right is not a non whitespace character `\S` and make the match case insensitive using `/i`

```
(?<!\S)au(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dt4OHa/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ZdM1h)

For example

```
$pattern = "/(?<!\S)au(?!\S)/i";
$data = <<<DATA
Japan is beautiful country.
AU is the telecom company of japan, au networks are very good.
Japan is famous for good restaurants.
Test $#au^&
DATA;

preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => AU
    [1] => au
)
```

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you very much .